# How can I perform an autocomplete function using jquery and CodeIgniter and mysql query?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I just need a little help here about creating  an autocomplete textbox. 
I found a solution with this but I can't integrate it with my code.
Here's my reference http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_16/How_to:_Autocomplete_with_CodeIgniter_and_jQuery

I followed this steps but It doesn't work for me. I think it is in my array. Because i created a loop that will display my rows and consist of textfields. 
Here's my code.

**In my view I have something like this**

Here's the Jquery part

```
  $("[id^=code]").keypress(function(e){

            var index = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];

            if(e.which == 13){
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            var searched = $('#code'+index).val();
            var fullurl = $('#codelist'+index).val() + 'index.php/item_controller/getResult/' + searched;

            $.getJSON(fullurl,function(result){
                //display suggestion code goes here
                var elements = [];

                $.each(result,function(i,val){
                    elements.push(val.title);
                });

                $('#code'+index).autocomplete({
                    source : elements;
                });

            });

        });
```

Here's the loop part

```
 for($i = 1; $i < 16; $i++){

                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>";
                                    echo "<input type='text' name='code[]' id='code{$i}' />";
                                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='codex[]' id='codelist{$i}' value='"base_url()"'/>";                                
                                echo "</td>";


                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='qty[]' id='qty{$i}' style='text-align: center' readonly='readonly' /></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='price[]' id='price{$i}' style='text-align: right;' onblur='' readonly='readonly'  /></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='total[]' id='total{$i}' style='font-family: courier; text-align: right; background-color: lightgray; color: red' readonly='readonly' value='' /></td>";
                            echo "<tr>";

                        }
```

And finally here's the part in my controller.

```
public function getResult($code){
        if(!empty($code) || isset($code)){  
            $this->db->like('order_code',$code);
            echo json_encode( $this->db->get('item')->result());
        }   
}
```

That's my code I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Any error error you got in the browser console panel plus do you have `title` column in your `item` table

Comment: you should user thie http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ liberary for autocomleate fully document and eady to use and you can customize